# A strange C++ error, maybe it is relative to the long long type

Tags: c++, output, long-integer

My code is the following:

```
#include <iostream>
int gcd(int a, int b) {
  //write your code here
  if(a==0){
    return b;
  }else if(b==0){
    return a;
  }else if(a>b){
    int a_pri=a%b;
    return gcd(b,a_pri);
  }else if(a<b){
    int b_pri=b%a;
    return gcd(a,b_pri);
  }else{
    return a;
  }
}
long long lcm(int a, int b) {
  int temp_gcd = gcd(a,b);
  long long abproduct = a*b;
  long long result = abproduct/temp_gcd;
  return result;
}

int main() {
  int a, b;
  std::cin >> a >> b;
  std::cout << lcm(a,b) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I would like to output the largest common multiple of two numbers.
but as I input two numbers 14159572 63967072 ,It output a negative number -527892768.But the correct answer should be 226436590403296.
 It looks like the output is cut off to 32bit.
so ,I print the variable `temp_gcd` ,it is 4.I changed the expression

```
long long result = abproduct/temp_gcd;
```

to

```
long long result = abproduct/4;
```

Then it outputs the right answer.

Comment: Suggest using unsigned types for everything: `%` operator doesn't work with negative right operand anyway, and so this gains you slightly more precision and avoids potential undefined behaviour due to overflow.  Perhaps use `uintmax_t`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're performing an `int` multiplication because that's the data type of the operands. Change that data type. I.e., change

```
long long lcm(int a, int b)
```

to

```
long long lcm(long long a, long long b)
```

Don't take the advice to use casts: a cast should always be the measure of last resort, like going to war (only after politicians and diplomats fail).

If you don't change the function signature then you can force a conversion by replacing `a*b` with `1LL*a*b`. But I don't recommend that here. Using proper data types is the right way to go.

Still, the code

```
long long abproduct = a*b;
long long result = abproduct/temp_gcd;
```

needlessly adds cases where the result can overflow. To reduce that,

```
long long result = a*(b/temp_gcd);
```

noting that this can't discard information (in general, though, you have to be careful about integer division discarding information).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is on the line `long long abproduct = a*b;`

Since `a` and `b` are both `int`, any operation on them will result in an `int`, which will result in an overflow in this case. Try casting either `a` or `b` to `long long` when doing the calculation.

`long long abproduct = (long long)a * b;`

Comment: Another way is `1LL * a * b`

Answer (score 0):

Didn't want to edit the @MahlerFive's answer - that should work too. I would cast a and b to long long like-so: `long long abproduct = static_cast<long long>(a)*static_cast<long long>(b)`.